# How to set a cartridge status as Inserted in IBM i 7.4 using IBM TS4300 tape library?

Tags: backup, ibm-midrange

I have a IBM TS4300 3555-L3A tape library. I'm using it for backing up IBM i 7.4. In green screen, my CL program takes selected cartridge to mount and save daily backup on it. The problem is that the selected cartridge should be "Inserted" status to mount but whenever I place a cartridge in I/O magazine (left one) physically, its status shown as "Available". I can't change its status to "Inserted".

I tried;
WRKTAPCTG command to set it,
restart the tape library device.

Thank you in advance.